# TCP forwarding over SSH with socat or any other tcp forwarder, on sshd with tcp forwarding disabled

Tags: networking, security, ssh, debian, tcp

What I am trying to do is have a user that can port forward, but only to a certain host and port.

I've disabled TCP forwarding over ssh for that user, and according to the manpage for sshd_config I should still be able to port forward with other tools, which I cannot figure out how to do.

EDIT: Found a better solution, using match and PermitOpen in the sshd_config

Answer (score -1):

ssh -L or ssh -R, depends what do you need :)

Comment: TCP forwarding is disabled on the sshd, and according to the manpage for sshd_config you can still use external tcp forwarders, the end result of this will be that this user will only be capable of connecting to one certain predefined host and port combination.

Comment: I guess this means, that en-/decapsuplation process can be attached to the ssh virtual terminal like the tar-pipe:
''tar -czf - | ssh $host "tar -xzf -"''. Instead of tarring, that application can open sockets and do stuff...